# Satisfy external symbols with static library exports

Tags: c++, gcc, ld

I'm trying to hook GCC's __cxa_throw so I'll be able to receive exception backtraces without cluttering exception objects themselves. While it worked well with executable, it doesn't work with shared objects.

I'm constructing tiny static library which contains hook itself and redirects it to my function in a separate SO. And my __cxa_throw appears nicely as exported symbol in .text section. Though it doesn't help, even with LD's -Bsymbolix, -Bsymbolic-functions.

So the question is. Can I force LD to find my existing implementation of __cxa_throw and satisfy external symbol with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, your hook function must be compiled into object file and linked into resulting SO as object file. Seems that symbols from object files have higher priority than even default imports like libstd. This should already satisfy all symbol references inside whole SO, including archives being linked in.

Second, if you want your hook to not be visible from outside world, just use `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`